# Move values in a data frame from one column to another based on matching criteria

Tags: json, r, dataframe

I am receiving output from a JSON object,however the JSON returns three fields sometimes two somtimes one, depending in the input. As a result I have a dataframe which looks like this:

```
       mixed     score     type
1          1 0.0183232 positive
2    neutral      <NA>     <NA>
3  -0.566558  negative     <NA>
4   0.473484  positive     <NA>
5   0.856743  positive     <NA>
6  -0.422655  negative     <NA>
```

Mixed can take values of 1 or 0
Score can take a positive or negative value between -1 and +1
Type can take a value of either positive, negative or neutral

I'm wondering how I can rearrange the values in the data.frame so that they are in the correct column i.e.

```
       mixed     score     type
1          1  0.018323  positive
2       <NA> <NA>        neutral
3       <NA> -0.566558  negative     
4       <NA>  0.473484  positive     
5       <NA>  0.856743  positive     
6       <NA> -0.422655  negative
```

Comment: How are you creating your data.frame from the JSON object? Have you taken a look at [jsonlite](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/jsonlite/index.html) ?

Comment: Depending on the input the JSON will return  up to three values for example $docSentiment
     score       type 
"0.856743" "positive" or something like this $docSentiment
     type 
"neutral"  So the return is mostly non-deterministic. The output is from the Alchemy API

Comment: @Tutochan Yes I am using jsonlite to return to the output to an object: response_json_temp <- fromJSON(text_for_export$Response)

Comment: I coded a solution which involves using 9 if statements and interates through each cell in each column and if a correct value is found it copies the matched value to a duplicate dataframe. (I'll post this later) But surely are more elegant solution exists?

Answer (score 0):

Not an elegant solution at all, but the best I could come up with.

```
### Seeds initial Dataframe 


mixed = c("1", "neutral", "0.473484", "-0.566558", "0.856743",  "-0.422655",  "-0.692675") 
score = c("0.0183232", "0", "positive", "negative", "positive", "negative", "negative")
type = c("positive", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0")

 df = data.frame(mixed, score, type) 


 # Create a new DF (3 cols by nrow ize) for output
 df <- as.data.frame(matrix(0, ncol = 3, nrow = i))
 setnames(df, old=c("V1","V2", "V3"), new=c("mixed", "score", "type"))
df 

 # Create a 2nd new DF (3 cols by nrow ize) for output
df.2 <- as.data.frame(matrix(0, ncol = 3, nrow = i))
 setnames(df.2, old=c("V1","V2", "V3"), new=c("mixed", "score", "type"))
 df.2 




#Check each column cell by cell if it does copy it do the shadow dataframe
# Set all <NA> values to Null
df[is.na(df)] <- 0



# Set interation length to column length
l <- 51

# Checked the mixed column for '1' and then copy it to the new frame
for(l in 1:l)

  if (df$mixed[l] == '1')
  {
    df.2$mixed[l] <-df$mixed[l]
  } 

# Checked the mixed column for a value which is less than 1 and then copy it to the score column in the new  frame

for(l in 1:l)

  if (df$mixed[l] < '1')
  {
    df.2$score[l] <-df$mixed[l]
  }

# Checked the mixed column for positive/negative/neutral and then copy it to the type column in the new  frame

for(l in 1:l)

  if (df$mixed[l] == "positive" | df$mixed[l] == "negative" | df$mixed[l] == "neutral")
  {
    df.2$type[l] <-df$mixed[l]
  }


# Checked the score column for '1' and then copy it to mixed column in  the new frame
for(l in 1:l)

  if (df$score[l] == '1')
  {
    df.2$mixed[l] <-df$score[l]
  } 

# Checked the score column for a value which is less than 1 and then copy it to the score column in the new  frame

for(l in 1:l)

  if (df$score[l] < '1')
  {
    df.2$score[l] <-df$score[l]
  }

# Checked the score column for positive/negative/neutral and then copy it to the type column in the new  frame

for(l in 1:l)

  if (df$score[l] == "positive" | df$score[l] == "negative" | df$score[l] == "neutral")
  {
    df.2$type[l] <-df$score[l]
  }



# Checked the type column for '1' and then copy it to mixed column in  the new frame **This one works***
for(l in 1:l)

  if (df$type[l] == '1')
  {
    df.2$mixed[l] <-df$type[l]
  } 

# Checked the type column for a value which is less than 1 and then copy it to the score column in the new  frame ** this one is erasing data in the new frame**

for(l in 1:l)

  if (df$type[l] < '1')
  {
    df.2$score[l] <-df$type[l]
  }

# Checked the type column for positive/negative/neutral and then copy it to the type column in the new  frame **This one works***

for(l in 1:l)

  if (df$type[l] == "positive" | df$type[l] == "negative" | df$type[l] == "neutral")
  {
    df.2$type[l] <-df$type[l]
  }
```